# Why is my Less outputting a promise error result instead of CSS?

Tags: javascript, less, gulp-less

I am trying to debug why gulp-less is not outputting correct CSS and throwing an exception. It seems like less.js seems to be not outputting CSS.

Here is my code:

```
 var accord         = require('accord');
 var less           = accord.load('less');

 less.render('.class { width: (1 + 1) }', {}, function (e, output) {console.log(output.css);})
```

The output is

```
{ state: 'fulfilled', value: { result: undefined } }
```

Instead of

```
.class {
  width: 2;
}
```

as expected on the website: http://lesscss.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra '{}' parameter, I just tried it after removing this and got the correct output. I just had less and accord installed in node_modules. The working code should be:

```
var accord         = require('accord');
var less           = accord.load('less');

 less.render('.class { width: (1 + 1) }', function (e, output) {console.log(output.css);})
```

The `{ state: 'fulfilled', value: { result: undefined } }` is just the error result of the promise returned by accord.

Comment: I thought that extra {} was just the options to less.render. I am still getting the same error. Not sure if it is the version of less. > var accord         = require('accord');
undefined
> var less           = accord.load('less');
undefined
>
>  less.render('.class { width: (1 + 1) }', function (e, output) {console.log(output.css);})
undefined
{ state: 'pending' }

Comment: Sorry, got it, thanks: less.render('.class  {width: (1 + 1)} ',  function (e, output) {console.log(output);})
.class {
  width: 2;
}

{ state: 'pending' }